# Messed up table with tabularx

Tags: tables

I would like to have all the values in the table aligned. However, when using tabularx, this looks even worse. I guess it may stem from the fact that I have something like this: \thead[l]{Potatoes \ Pasta \ Rice}, because in my other table (11) that only has single words, tabularx works just fine. [image]

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
       \centering
       \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
       \begin{tabular}[width=\textwidth]{l l l l l l l}
       \hline
       \hline
        \multicolumn{7}{c}{Price} \\
       \hline
          & Meat & Dairy & Vegetables & Fruits & \thead[l]{Potatoes \\ Pasta \\ Rice} & \thead[l]{Bread \\ Oats}  \\
          \hline
          \hline
          Meat &  -1.017***   &  0.044***  &  -0.090***  &  -0.140***  &  -0.049***  &  -0.165***\\
          
          Dairy &   0.097***  &  -1.009***  &  -0.044***  &  -0.009  &      0.030***  &  -0.021**\\
          
          Fruits  &  0.000   &    -0.044***  &  -0.688***  &   0.006  &      -0.039***   &  0.020 \\
          
          Vegetables &  -0.089*** &    0.057***  &   0.025*  &    -0.673*** &   -0.001    &    0.009\\
          
          \thead[l]{Potatoes \\ Pasta \\ Rice}   & -0.194***  &  -0.046** &     -0.016   &    -0.073***  &  -0.780***  &  -0.043*\\
          
          \thead[l]{Bread \\ Oats}   &  0.003  &     -0.099***  &  -0.118***  &  -0.047**  &    0.010    &   -0.496***\\ 
          \hline
          \hline
           \multicolumn{7}{c}{\footnotesize  * p$<$0.1, ** p$<$0.05, *** p$<$0.01}
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{First stage estimation of own- and cross-price elasticities}
       \label{cross_price_1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
       \centering
       \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
       \begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{XSSS}
       \hline
       \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{Price} \\
       \hline
          & {Beef} & {Pork} & {Poultry}  \\
          \hline
          \hline
          Beef & -0.494***   &  -0.516***  & -0.228***   \\
          
          Pork & -0.048***   &  -0.903***   &  0.008  \\
          
          Poultry  &   -0.209***  &   -0.082**  &  -0.822***  \\
          \hline
          \hline
           \multicolumn{4}{c}{\footnotesize  * p$<$0.1, ** p$<$0.05, *** p$<$0.01}
       \end{tabularx}
       \caption{Second stage estimation of own- and cross-price elasticities}
       \label{cross_price_2m}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend your sniplet to an actual minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Here we have to add stuff in order to even get this to compile, and w might add stuff that aren't in your setup

Comment: Note that unless you are using some special package,  `\begin{tabular}[width=\textwidth]{l l l l l l l}` is the wrong syntax. Tabularx uses `\begin{tabularx}{width}{...}`

Comment: That edit is still not compilable. There is no `\begin/end{document}` and note my second comment.

Comment: And  `\thead` is not defined.You miss something else ...

Comment: Sorry missed the second table, but the first is still wrong, `tabular` does not take a width like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- At such tables are usual used `S` columns defined in `siunitx` package, which enable align numbers at decimal points.
- You use `\thead` command defined in the `makecell` packae, but not load this package.
- To `tabular` you cant prescribe table width. This is possible at `tabular*`
- try the following MWE (Minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell,    % <---
            tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
   \centering
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
   \sisetup{table-format=-1.3{***}}
            
   \begin{tabular}{l *{6}{S}}
       \hline
       \hline
       \multicolumn{7}{c}{Price} \\
       \hline
        & {Meat} & {Dairy} & {Vegetables} & {Fruits} & {\thead[l]{Potatoes \\ Pasta \\ Rice}} & {\thead[l]{Bread \\ Oats}}  \\
          \hline
          \hline
Meat    & -1.017*** &  0.044*** & -0.090*** & -0.140*** & -0.049*** & -0.165***     \\
Dairy   &  0.097*** & -1.009*** & -0.044*** & -0.009    &  0.030*** & -0.021**      \\
Fruits  &  0.000    & -0.044*** & -0.688*** &  0.006    & -0.039*** &  0.020        \\
Vegetables 
        & -0.089*** &  0.057*** &  0.025*   & -0.673*** & -0.001    &  0.009        \\
\thead[l]{Potatoes \\ Pasta \\ Rice}   
        & -0.194*** & -0.046**  & -0.016    & -0.073*** & -0.780*** & -0.043*       \\
\thead[l]{Bread \\ Oats}   
        &  0.003    & -0.099*** & -0.118*** & -0.047**  &  0.010    & -0.496***     \\
    \hline
    \hline
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\footnotesize  * p$<$0.1, ** p$<$0.05, *** p$<$0.01}
    \end{tabular}
\caption{First stage estimation of own- and cross-price elasticities}
\label{cross_price_1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]